# Reference resource from variable in terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

I want to create an object through which I will iterate using `for_each` to create some:

- `google_service_account`
- `google_project_iam_member`

resources

So my object is more or less like this

```
  service_accounts = {
    "gha_storage_admin_sa" = {
      create       = true
      project      = var.project_id
      account_id   = "id1"
      display_name = "GHA service account 1"
      role         = "roles/storage.admin"
    },
    "gha_cluster_scaling_sa" = {
      create       = false
      project      = var.project_id
      account_id   = "id2"
      display_name = "GHA service account 2"
      role         = google_organization_iam_custom_role.my_custom_role.id
    },
  }
```

```
resource "google_service_account" "service_account" {
  for_each = {
    for k, v in local.service_accounts: k => v
        if v.create
  }

  project      = each.value.project
  account_id   = each.value.account_id
  display_name = each.value.display_name
}


resource "google_project_iam_member" "member" {
  for_each = local.service_accounts

  project = var.project_id
  role    = each.value.role
  member  = "serviceAccount:${google_service_account.service_account[each.key].email}"
}
```

This works fine if the above is a `local` variable.

I want however to expose it as a regular `variable`.

My question is whether the referenced resource (`google_organization_iam_custom_role.my_custom_role.id`) in the second element can be somehow exposed as a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is whether the referenced resource (google_organization_iam_custom_role.my_custom_role.id) in the second element can be somehow exposed as a variable.

Sadly its **not possible**. TF does not support dynamic variables. All variables' values must be know at plan time. You have to pass the actual value of `google_organization_iam_custom_role.my_custom_role.id` as input variable to your code.

Comment: and how would you know the value if it hasnt been created yet?  struggling with the same thing where i cant to keep what ami data i will use configurable in  varaibles file...but cant do something like "data.aws_ami.ami_default.id"